# Create user and privileges to DB in MySQL VIA script

Tags: mysql, scripting, privileges

I need to create a script that can create a user/password and grant then certain privileges on a local DB.

Thanks in advance!

-Sol

Answer (score 0):

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DB.* TO 'user'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```